# HTML Rewriting the URL of a Link

Tags: html

I am creating a website on GoDaddy's Windows Plesk Web Hosting, and I am using subdomains as different ages of the website. I have designed a navigation bar with links to these subdomains. When you open the website and try to click on the links, it redirects to "domain.com/subdomain.domain.com" instead of what I put in, which was "subdomain.domain.com" so basically, no matter what I put in for a URL, it automatically puts "domain.com/" in front of it. I spoke with GoDaddy support and they told me it had to be something in my coding, which makes sense. But I can't find anything that would cause this. If it makes a difference, I had originally hosted this site with tumblr and just copied the coding over to GoDaddy, and just changed the URLs. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!
CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<HTML>

<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://freefavicons.org/download/house/house.png">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script.js">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script.css">

<Title>William Ryan Realty</Title>

<style type="text/css">

@font-face { font-family: "bebas neue"; src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/cvlbtjz/cnsln9tpp/bebasneue.otf'); }

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Coming+Soon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

logo {

position:center;

margin-top:-20px;


}



div.main_content {

width:900px;

position:center;

font-size:12px;

}



div.left_column {
float:left
width: px;
height: px;
padding: 2px;
border: px dashed gray;
background-color: ;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right:230px;
}

div.left_column_two {
float:left
width: px;
height: px;
padding: 2px;
border: px dashed gray;
background-color: ;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right:230px;
}


div.right_column {
float:right;
width:220px;
height: 210px;
padding: 2px;
border: px dashed gray;
background-color: ;
margin-top:1px;
}

div.right_column_two {
float:right;
width:220px;
height:;
padding:px;
border:px dashed gray;
background-color:;
box-shadow:;
margin-top:60px;
margin-right:-223px;
text-align:center;
}

div.right_column_three {
float:right;
width:220px;
height:;
padding:px;
border:px dashed gray;
background-color:;
box-shadow:;
margin-top:150px;
margin-right:-223px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
list-style-type:none;
}

div.right_column_four {
float:right;
width:220px;
height:;
padding:px;
border:px dashed gray;
background-color:;
box-shadow:;
margin-top:165px;
margin-right:-223px;
text-align:center;

}

a {
font-family:"bebas neue";
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:gray;
}

#wrap   {
width: 100%; 
height: 50px; 
margin: 0; 
z-index: 99; 
position: relative; 
background-color: ;
}
.navbar {
height: 50px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute; 
border-right: 1px solid #cc0000; 
}
.navbar li {
height: auto;
width: 165px; 
float: left; 
text-align: center; 
list-style: none; 
font: normal bold 22px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica; 
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: maroon;
}
.navbar a   {   
padding: 22px 0; 
border-left: 1px solid #cc0000;
border-right: 1px solid #660000; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: white; 
display: block;
}
.navbar li:hover, a:hover {background-color: }
.navbar li ul {
display: none; 
height: auto;   
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}   

.navbar li:hover ul {
display: block; 
}
.navbar li ul li {background-color: #cc0000;} 
.navbar li ul li a {
border-left: 1px solid #660000; 
border-right: 1px solid #660000; 
border-top: 1px solid #660000; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #660000; 
}

.navbar li ul li a:hover    {background-color: maroon;}

icon {

width:70px;

height:70px;
}
body {

background-image: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/30i9ous.png");

background-color:maroon;

background-repeat:;

background-position:stretch;

font-size:12px;

font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;

}

p {

color:maroon;

font-family: ;

font-size:19px;

}

h3 {

color:black;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:bold;
text-align:left;
}

h2 {
color:black;

font-family:"bebas neue";

font-size:30px;

text-decoration:bold;

text-shadow: 1px 1px gray;

}

h4 {
color:white;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:bold;
}



div.footer {
width: px;
height: px;
padding: px;
border: px dashed gray;
background-color: ;
margin-bottom: -10px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
position:relative;

}

div.question {
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 530px;
top:30px;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}

.hidden {
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div id="wrap">
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="listings.williamryanrealty.com">Our Listings</a></li>

<li><a href="properties.williamryanrealty.com">Search Properties</a></li>

<li><a href="buyer.williamryanrealty.com">Buyer Resources</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="eightsteps.williamryanrealty.com">Eight Steps to Buying Your Home</a></li>
<li><a href="wishlist.williamryanrealty.com">Creating Your Home Wishlist</a></li>
<li><a href="location.williamryanrealty.com">Location, Location, Location</a></li>
<li><a href="agenthelp.williamryanrealty.com">How Can an Agent Help Me?</a></li>
<li><a href="eightquestions.williamryanrealty.com">Eight Important Questions to Ask Your Agent</a></li>
<li><a href="videos.williamryanrealty.com">Property Videos</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="seller.williamryanrealty.com">Seller Resources</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="eightstepsselling.williamryanrealty.com">Eight Steps to Selling Your Home</a></li>
<li><a href="helpselling.williamryanrealty.com">How Can an Agent Help me Sell my Home?</a></li>
<li><a href="pricetosell.williamryanrealty.com">How to Price to Sell and Still Make a Profit</a></li>
<li><a href="etiquette.williamryanrealty.com">Good Seller's Etiquette</a></li>
<li><a href="understandingbuyer.williamryanrealty.com">Understanding the Buyer</a></li>
<li><a href="increasingappeal.williamryanrealty.com">Increasing Your Home's Appeal</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.williamryanrealty.com">Contact us About Selling Your Home</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="about.williamryanrealty.com">About</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="testimonials.williamryanrealty.com">Testimonials</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.williamryanrealty.com">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="videos.williamryanrealty.com">Property Videos</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
<img id="logo"> 
<br>
<br>
<center><img src="http://s30.postimg.org/ll2lunoip/banner.png">
</div>
<div id="main_content">
<div class="column">
<div class="right_column">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/luxuryhomeslakewinnipesaukee"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/15frk11.png" width="50"></a><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/welcomehomenh"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/25tc47k.png" width="50"></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcyEuwW9KDnfCaHOYRlw1TA"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/npexwo.png" width="50"></a><a href="http://www.linkedin/in/billryanbroker"><img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2iazx8k.png" width="50"></a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="column">
<div class="right_column_two">
<a href="members.williamryanrealty.com"><img src="http://s13.postimg.org/wtuy82hbr/membership_copy.png" width="200"></a>


</div>
</div>


<div class="column">
<div class="right_column_four">


<a href="properties.williamryanrealty.com"><img src="http://s16.postimg.org/42bink8hh/search_properties_copy.png" width="200"></a>

<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="column">
<div class="left_column">
<a href="weekly.williamryanrealty.com"><img src="http://s30.postimg.org/b3fq8yd8h/video_of_the_week_banner.png"></a>

</div>
</div>


<div class="footer">


<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/lnm2rpunr/updated_footer_copy.png">
</div>
</div>


</div>


</div>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to begin URLs with the scheme for the browser to navigate to another domain. begin your href attributes with `http://`

```
<li><a href="http://listings.williamryanrealty.com/">Our Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="http://properties.williamryanrealty.com/">Search Properties</a></li>
<li><a href="http://buyer.williamryanrealty.com/">Buyer Resources</a>
...
```